# If we know initial acceleration and initial velocity, what can we deduce?

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation, kinematics

I am working on a problem, and have deduced that both the initial acceleration and velocity (time 0) of a particle are zero. Can we deduce that the particle remains at a constant position? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So I can never move this stationary pencil in front of me, because it currently has zero acceleration and velocity? Put in terms a physicist might prefer, the current net force must be nil. But suppose the force changes with time?

Comment: As long as no forces act on this particle for $t>0$, by Newton's Law, the particle will remain at rest. Knowing the acceleration and velocity of a particle at one point in time is not enough to determine it's position for all time.